# advice when talking to canadian passport control agent when speaking at a conference?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, canada, conferences

I have been advised as such by a friend if and when I go to passport control in Canada-

> Summary:  The less you say the better.  You are attending a software
>   technical conference.  the end.
>
> You are not "working" with or for it or anything that might sound like
>   work.  "volunteering" is work. If you hint that you might help out
>   the reg desk, it is their job to get things evaluated by the labor
>   dept that understands the labor market etc and that takes a minimum of
>   3 days. As long as you don't leave the country with a bag of money
>   they don't care what you did at the conference.
>
> My wife spoke at a technical conference in Montreal. That fact got her
>   a round of questions, mostly "are you being paid to speak?"   - I
>   would avoid saying anything other than "attending."
>
> If pressed for details, I would not lie.

I do know if this post-trump or this was always there and it doesn't matter as well. Has anybody have any experiences at passport control while going to attend/speak at conferences in Canada ?

I have put up for a travel bursary and from what has been shared with me, selection of talks does influence travel bursaries quite a bit.

Comment: This has absolutely **nothing** to do, in any way, with the Trump Administration.  Are you paying to attended the conference or are you being compensated, even for travel, to present?

Comment: @Johns-305 have edited the question to have more clarity.

Comment: Umm - you do surely realize that Canada and the USA are separate countries with different governments and different leaders ... ?

Comment: yes, I do realize that.. but also realize the fact that neighbouring countries might be influenced (in good and bad ways) with changes in neighbouring country policies as well. For instance, UK and Australia have followed Trump's policies but this will all lead to off-topic chat and not a direction I want to go anyway.

Comment: Off topic I know, but how exactly have Australia followed Trump's policies? I'd just delete the bit about Trump and be done with it. It is a distraction to your real question.

Comment: @John3136 thank you, was thinking the same. Although one could argue Trump's 'America first' to Asutralia's 'Australia first' luanched just sometime back. The visa policy, changes in H1-B policy in States, visa 457 in Australia, policy against the big three Middle-east airliners by both the countries, I could go on but as shared this isn't the platform for that.

Answer (score 7):

I've done this for many years, which means it long predates any recent governmental changes.

What is written is good advice. However it should also be coupled with 'always tell the truth if asked'. If they ask if you are speaking and you are, say 'yes'.  The advice is more for the avoidance of more detailed questioning.